# Can't get NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification to fire for stdout pipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsfilehandle

We need to capture stdout in iOS because we are using an open source project that communicates via stdin/stdout

This works:

```
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSFileHandle *readh = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

dup2([[pipe fileHandleForWriting] fileDescriptor], fileno(stdout));

[@"Hello iOS World!" writeToFile:@"/dev/stdout" atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSData *data = [readh availableData];
NSLog(@"%d", [data length]);
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@%@", @"stdout captured:", str);
```

The console prints:

```
2015-10-04 12:03:29.396 OpeningExplorer[857:42006] 16
2015-10-04 12:03:29.397 OpeningExplorer[857:42006] stdout captured:Hello iOS World!
```

However the above example blocks. Why doesn't the following async code work?

```
    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSFileHandle *readh = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    dup2([[pipe fileHandleForWriting] fileDescriptor], fileno(stdout));

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                                                        object:readh
                                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = (NSFileHandle*) [note object];
        NSLog(@"inside listener");
        NSData *data = [fileHandle availableData];
        NSLog(@"%d", [data length]);
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@%@", @"stdout captured:", str);

    }];
    [readh waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];

    [@"Hello iOS World!" writeToFile:@"/dev/stdout" atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

The notification code block doesn't seem to be called - the console doesn't output anything

Comment: What does the program do after writing the string? Does it return the run loop?

Comment: The code is in a method that is run when a UI button is selected. I'm embarrassed to say I don't know what a run loop is - can you elaborate?

Comment: [Apple's explanation of run loops.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) The main event loop of an app is built on top of a run loop, so it sounds like you're probably good in that respect. I brought it up because the docs for `-waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify` say "You must call this method from a thread that has an active run loop." If you had, for example, blocked while waiting for the notification, that would not have worked.

Comment: I found the problem thanks to your question. I had forgotten that I was running the code above using an NSThread. When run from the main thread the code above works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilehandle/1409270-waitfordatainbackgroundandnotify?language=objc) on `waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify`: "You must call this method from a thread that has an active run loop."

That means you can't call this from within an `NSOperationQueue` or an `NSThread`. So make sure this code is running from your main UI thread, not a background thread.

(Posted in case anyone is lazy like me and doesn't want to parse through the comments to find the answer..)